# Are the latin root word "dis" and latin words "bis" and "duo" synonyms?

Tags: etymology

On [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dis-?ref=etymonline_crossreference), it is stated that the prefix "dis" is related to the latin words "bis" and "duo."

Can it be correct to say that all three words are/were synonyms to each other?

Answer (score 3):

Related words/affixes share the same root, but this does not imply being synonyms.

***duo*, *bis*, *dis-* are not synonyms**, they have different meanings and are not interchangeable.

PIE **dwóh₁*, Latin *duo* is a numeral meaning "two".

PIE **dwís*, Latin *bis* is an adverb meaning "twice, two times", so its grammatical usage is clearly different. Similarly in English you cannot replace "I ate two oranges." with "I ate twice oranges.".
(Old Latin /dw/ (spelled <du> or <> in old alphabet) [regularly changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin#Other_sequences) to /b/. E.g.  *([duenos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duenos#Latin))* -> *duonos* -> *[duonus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duonus#Latin)* -> *bonus*; **duellom* -> *[duellum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duellum#Latin)* -> *bellum*)

Latin *dis-* prefix may come from PIE **dwís*, but it has developed several different meanings in Latin (or Proto-Italic), one of them being "reversal, removal". *difficilis* ("difficult") is clearly not **bis facilis* ("*twice easy").

Michiel de Vaan (2008, "Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages"):

> **dis-** 'away, apart' [pref.] (Andr.+)
>
> Derivatives: *dī-* (in front of *b*,*d*,*g*,*l*,*m*,*n*,*v*,*r*; *dismota* SCBac.), *dir-* (in front of vowels), *dif-* (in front of *f*).
>
> PIt. **dis-* 'in two, apart'; **dus-* 'bad' (in *difficilis*). It. cognates: possibly U. *disleralinsust* [3s.fut.pf.] '?will have gone wrong' < **dis-leis-?*
>
> PIE **dus* 'into two > bad', **dui-* 'two, into two'. IE cognates: Gr. *διά* 'in two, apart, through' [adv.], 'through' [prep.] < **δισ-α*; also *δα-* in *δαφοινός*, esp. from animals, 'very red', *δάσκιος* 'very shady', developed from *δια-*, or Aeol. *ζα-*.
>
> Borrowed into Gothic as the prefix *dis-* 'apart'. Lat. dis- seems to be cognate with Gr. *διά* < **δισ-α*. Whereas *διά* can function both as a preverb and as a preposition, in Latin, *dis-* is only a preverb. In the older texts, it is nearly always prefixed to verbs, with the exception of the adj. *difficilis*. Exactly in this compound, *dis-* does not mean 'away, apart', but rather 'non-, opposite'. Therefore, it may well be that *difficilis* contains PIE **dus-* 'apart; bad' (thus Wackernagel and Leumann 1977: 400), which is otherwise unattested in Latin. Yet Forssman 1992: 309 maintains that *difficilis* was built from *dis* + *facilis* on the example of *similis* : *dissimilis*. Even if *difficilis* does not directly continue **dus-*, the restriction of *dis-* to (verbal) compounds would suggest that all of Latin *dis-* is a remake of **dus-* by analogy with **dui-* 'into two, apart'. Another possibility is a dissimilation **dwis-* > **dis-* in front of verbs starting in **w-*, especially in the compounds *dīvidere* 'to divide' and *dīvertere* 'to divert'. Yet a separation of *dis-* from *διά-* is unattractive; and in Greek, *δυσ-* has remained alive as a
> prefix - but meaning 'bad'. Hence, Proto-Greek may have had all three forms: **dus-* 'bad, **du̯i-* 'two' and **dis-(a-)* 'into two, apart'. Whereas **dus-* developed from 'into two' to metaphorical 'bad', the novel form **dis-* retained the literal meaning 'into two, apart'.

Sometimes related words may even be antonyms:

PIE [*upó](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/up%C3%B3), Latin [sub](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub#Latin) "under, below"

PIE [*upér](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/up%C3%A9r), Latin [super](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/super#Latin) "over, above"

Comment: This answer has very good information. I have two more questions: *"Latin dis- prefix may come from PIE \*dwís"* : does that mean "it is possible that it came", or "although it came"? 2. Could you confirm or deny that all three morphemes are ultimately from the same Indo-European root?

Comment: @Cerberus: Dictionaries say that they are ultimately from the same root, however they present different paths for *dis-*. Wiktionary says that Latin [dis-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dis-#Latin) developed from Proto-Italic ＊dwis-, while Etymonline says that [dis-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dis-) prefix existed already in PIE: 「The Latin prefix is from PIE ＊dis- "apart, asunder" (source also of Old English te-, Old Saxon ti-, Old High German ze-, German zer-). The PIE root is a secondary form of ＊dwis-」. I am undecided about which path is more probable.

Comment: Old Latin initial /dw/ supposedly [regularly changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin#Other_sequences) to /b/, so *＊dwis* -> *bis* is regular, while *＊dwis-* -> *dis-* seems less regular...

Comment: Ok very interesting. Maybe add some of that to your answer?

Comment: Have you checked De Vaan? `Pit. *dis- 'in two, apart'; *dus- 'bad' (in difficilis); PIE *dus 'into two > bad', *dui- 'two, into two'.`

Comment: I checked it later. I now added full quote to my answer.